# awk to print 3 lines above match until second match

Tags: unix, awk

I have a long list of lines and I want to selectively print START + 3 lines above until END including. The problem is that the length between START and END is variable, but I always want the three lines above start.
I tried awk :

```
awk '/START/,/END/' file.txt
```

However I cant find out a way on how to include the three lines above START. 
Any hint would really be appreciated 
thanks!

**Input**

```
EFA  
DAD  
ABC  
DEF  
GEF  
START  
EDG  
EFG  
GAD  
END  
CDA
```

**Result**

```
ABC  
DEF  
GEF  
START  
EDG  
EFG  
GAD  
END
```

Comment: Do START and END appear more than once? Or just once?

Comment: ...and if they do, do you want to print from the first START to the last END or first start to first END or every START to END block or something else?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/START/ { if (a) print a; if (b) print b; if (c) print c; }\
     { a=b; b=c; c=$0; }\
     /START/,/END/' file.txt
```

**Explanation**

`/START/{if(a)print a;if(b)print b;if(c)print c}` when a line matching `/START/` is encountered print the buffer records, skipping any that are empty.

`{a=b;b=c;c=$0}` shift buffer records, if many more are needed than an array can be used.

`/START/,/END/` print all records between `/START/` and `/END/`

Answer (score 1):

```
#!awk -f
{
  foo[NR] = $0
}
/START/ {
  bar = NR - 3
}
/END/ {
  while (bar++ <= NR)
    print foo[bar]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/START/{print x3"\n"x2"\n"x;p=1}
     /END/{print;p=0}
     {x3=x2}
     {x2=x}
     {x=$0}p' your_file
```

Tested:

```
> cat temp
EFA  
DAD  
ABC  
DEF  
GEF  
START  
EDG  
EFG  
GAD  
END  
CDA  
> awk '/START/{print x3"\n"x2"\n"x;p=1}/END/{print;p=0}{x3=x2}{x2=x}{x=$0}p' temp
ABC  
DEF  
GEF  
START  
EDG  
EFG  
GAD  
END  
>
```

Answer (score 1):

A similar, but maybe an easier-to-understand variation for the same theme:

```
awk '/START/{for(i=1;i<4;++i)if(NR-i in a)print a[NR-i]}{a[NR]=$0;delete a[NR-3]}/START/,/END/' inputfile
```

In the middle it just stores the last three lines and drops if there is a fourth one. If the string `START` is found, it prints the three previous lines (only if they exists) and anything between `START` and `END`.

If `START` and `END` should be exact, then the pattern should be `/^START$/` and `/^END$/` or instead of pattern matching a direct string comparison should be used like `$0=="START"` in all cases.

Input file:

```
GEF  
START  
EDG  
EFG  
GAD  
END  
CDA
EFA  
DAD  
ABC  
DEF  
GEF  
START  
EDG  
EFG  
GAD  
END  
CDA
```

Output:

```
GEF  
START  
EDG  
EFG  
GAD  
END  
GEF  
DEF  
ABC  
START  
EDG  
EFG  
GAD  
END
```

Answer (score 0):

If START and END appear just once, you can use `grep` with context like this:

```
grep -B 3 -A 99999 START file | grep -B 99999 END
```

i.e.  3 lines `before` START and up to 99999 lines after, then up to 99999 lines before END.

Answer (score 0):

Using tac

Should work if multiple END/STARTS in the file

```
tac file | awk '/END/{x=4}y&&x{x--}/START/{y=x}x' | tac
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted haha ? Can you leave a comment in future to explain please :)

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to one possible interpretation of your requirements:

```
$ awk '{a[NR]=$0} /START/{s=NR} /END/{for (i=(s-3);i<=NR;i++) print a[i]}' file
ABC
DEF
GEF
START
EDG
EFG
GAD
END
```

Will work if there's 1 or more START/END blocks and you do not want first START to last END.